# tx.executeSQL(''); is not envoked from second Page of application

Tags: android, sqlite, cordova, web-sql

```
function onDeviceReady() {
    var db = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({name: "mydb"});
    alert("open");
    db.transaction(function(tx) {   
          alert("transaction");
          tx.executeSql('select * from mytable',[],function(tx,rs) {
            alert("select");
           });

    });

}
```

I have two pages in my application, index.html and second.html.
If I call this code on index.html, it alerts correctly "open"-"transaction"-"select". But when I leave index.html and go to second.html afterwards, it does not alert "select",  neither does it throw an Exception or call the error callback function which I optionally include. It just does nothing besides alerting "open"-"transaction". If I go directly to second.html without calling the script from index.html, it works well. The problem seems to occur only, when the script -or parts of it - is called for the second time.
Who can help?

Comment: Are you waiting for deviceready to fire on the second page?

Comment: possible duplicate of [callback function is not called, neither is errorHandler](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25387492/callback-function-is-not-called-neither-is-errorhandler)

Comment: Solved: The program works only for single pages.